# ArgoCD doesn't sync correctly to OCI Helm chart?

Tags: argocd

Situation:
My ArgoCD app is created and synced to Azure OCI Registry Helm chart. (ex: Chart version 1.0.0).
Synchronize was successful at the first time.
But after I delete the Helm Chart version 1.0.0 from Azure OCI registry (ACR), ArgoCD still show that sync successful when I click on `Sync` button. (I expect the Syncing Error happen)

Question:

- ArgoCD stored Helm chart v1.0.0 and not pull it again when I click Sync button, is that right?
- If I push some changes overwrite the Helm Chart version 1.0.0 on OCI, How can I force ArgoCD pull the charts once more time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In argocd do a hard refresh (the dropdown icon on the refresh button). This should detect it.

In the mean time this feature request has been opened: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/9499

Comment: I just clicked on the hard refresh button but still the updated helm chart is not detected it seems.